# iOS NSDictionary saved to NSUserDefaults not saving values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save a `NSDictionary` with array values to `NSUserDefaults` but am having some strange trouble.

My `NSDictionary` has `NSStrings` for `keys` and each `value` is a `NSArray` of `NSNumbers`. When I print the dictionary out, everything is fine. I write this dictionary to `NSUserDefaults` and if I read it back out right away, everything seams fine. Using this everything seams just fine:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.selectedOptionPositions 
                                          forKey:PREF_OPTIONS_KEY];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

//THIS PRINT EVERYTHING OUT EXACTLY AS IT SHOULD!       
NSLog(@"read after write: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
                                 objectForKey:PREF_OPTIONS_KEY]);
```

The problem comes when I create a new instance of the class that handles this. When I make a new instance of the class and in the init method check the `NSDictionary` like so:

```
NSLog(@"read initial: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
                              objectForKey:PREF_OPTIONS_KEY]);
```

When I print that logging, the `NSDictionary` contains all of the *keys* but all of the `values` are now empty! All newly added `keys` exist after recreating the class, but no `values` persist.

What could be wrong here? There are no warnings or errors in the console.

Comment: Try using [self.selectedOptionPositions copy] while saving to NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

You can use NSKeyedArchiver to write out your dictionary to an NSData, which you can store among the preferences.

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.selectedOptionPositions];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:PREF_OPTIONS_KEY];
```

For retrieving data:

```
NSData *dictionaryData = [defaults objectForKey:PREF_OPTIONS_KEY];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dictionaryData];
```

As in the [iOS Developer Documentation for NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it says that:

> NSKeyedArchiver, a concrete subclass of NSCoder, provides a way to
>   encode objects (and scalar values) into an architecture-independent
>   format that can be stored in a file. When you archive a set of
>   objects, the class information and instance variables for each object
>   are written to the archive. NSKeyedArchiver’s companion class,
>   NSKeyedUnarchiver, decodes the data in an archive and creates a set of
>   objects equivalent to the original set.

Comment: Could you also explain the difference this code will have? For everybody's understanding.

Comment: Also You should use NSKeyedUnarchiver to get dictionary back. Exmaple : NSDictionary * userInfo = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:PREF_OPTIONS_KEY]];