# Swift NSUserDefaults not saving Dictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, nsuserdefaults

Here is my code. I have been solving this bug for a month but it is still not solved.

Here are my codes.

```
 var color : String = ""
 var colorSentDictionary = Dictionary<String, Int>()

 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // load colorSentDictionary
    self.loadColorSentDictionary()

}


func loadColorSentDictionary () {

    // load total messages sent
    var defaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if (defaults.dictionaryForKey("colorSentDictionary") != nil) {
        var colorSentDictionary : NSDictionary = defaults.dictionaryForKey("colorSentDictionary")!
        self.colorSentDictionary = colorSentDictionary as Dictionary
    }
}

func saveColorSentDictionary () {

    // save total messages received
    var defaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var colorSentDictionary : NSDictionary = self.colorSentDictionary
    defaults.setObject(colorSentDictionary, forKey: "colorSentDictionary")
    defaults.synchronize()


    if (defaults.dictionaryForKey("colorSentDictionary") != nil) {
        println("It is not nil !!!!!!!!!") } else { println("It is nil") }
}


@IBAction func sendMessage(sender : AnyObject) {

self.color = "Yellow"

println("The color of the message is: \(self.color)")

    // add value to messageSentDictionary
    if (self.colorSentDictionary["\(self.color)"] != nil) {
        var colorSentCount : Int = self.colorSentDictionary[self.color]!
        self.colorSentDictionary["\(self.color)"] = colorSentCount+1
        println("It exists")
    } else {
        self.colorSentDictionary["\(self.color)"] = 1
        println("Not exist")
    }

    self.saveColorSentDictionary()

    self.navigationController!.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Whenever I trigger the save method, the colorSentDictionary is always not saved. The log prints "It is nil" as it cannot find the key "colorSentDictionary".

But if I put self.saveColorSentDictionary () in viewWillAppear, the dictionary is saved and the log prints "It is not nil !!!!!!!!".

I think this problem is weird but however I don't think it is a bug since I tested it in the official release version of Xcode 6. Can someone please solve this for me? Thanks :)

Comment: Show us the code where you “trigger the save method”.

Comment: Xcode 7 ??? Man you know something that we don't

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501998/ios-nsdictionary-saved-to-nsuserdefaults-not-saving-values

Comment: @SamBudda Sorry I meant Xcode 6 haha

Comment: @robmayoff It is in the IBAction, which is linked to a button.

Comment: Can someone help me out? I have the exact the same code in another viewController and it works perfectly fine. The only differences are the name and the save method is not called before the viewController pops back to the previous controller.